# Https.request() inside an async function doesn't get called

Tags: node.js

I'm still new to nodejs. My problem is that I have async function that is awaited in the "main" function that contains https.request() but the program doesn't go inside it.

Below is how my code is formatted.

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    var responseBody = await getNextCorrId();
    console.log(responseBody);
};

async function getNextCorrId(event){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'something',
            path: 'something',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept':'something',
                'Content-Type':'something',
                'Authorization': 'something'
            },
        };
        const req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            console.log("Went inside request");
            res.on('end', function () {
                var responseBody = "Well hello there";
                resolve(responseBody );
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });
        req.end();
    });
}
```

I'm expecting when I `console.log(responseBody)` I should get a

```
"Went inside request"
"Well hello there"
```

in the console. Instead I get [object Promise]

Comment: Where you are doing console.log(responseBody)??

Comment: @ShubhDixit inside the main function. Will update the post thanks.

Comment: Yes please update

Comment: Thanks I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove keyword `async` before function `getNextCorrId(event)`. Adding `async` keyword wraps a returning value from a function into a Promise object. However you return a Promise from your function, which means that it actually returns a Promise in a Promise. And when you `await` it, you still get a Promise, the inner one. Later versions of Node.js seem to have this thing optimized, if they see similar things occurred in runtime, they automatically unwrap upper Promise for you.